# How to retrieve DHCP information when using systemd-networkd?

Tags: dhcp, systemd-networkd

Our Ubuntu 22 machines have networking configured using `netplan` and `systemd-networkd`. Network manager (and therefore `nmcli` & co.) are **not** installed.

In a `bash` script, I am looking to extract various parameters received by the DHCP server, in particular the host name and DNS domain name. With `nmcli` I could easily dump the DHCP information; however, I do not see a similar possibility with `systemd-networkd`.

One option would be to parse the DHCP lease file in `/run/systemd/netif/leases/`. However, the file starts so:

```
# This is private data. Do not parse.
ADDRESS=128.XXX.YYY.ZZZ
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
...
```

Of course I can parse the file anyway, but if the comment is there, it probably means that there is no guarantee whatsoever that the contents are parseable or wont change format at the next systemd update.

Is there a proper way to retrieve this information? I found for the hostname that `hostnamectl` can be used so:

```
hostnamectl --json=short | jq '.Hostname'
```

However, this only extracts the current hostname of the machine (as reported anyway by the `hostname` command, and I have no guarantee this corresponds to the DHCP host name), or the contents of the `/etc/hostname` file if I use `.StaticHostname`.

What can I do if I want to stop parsing the file that should not be parsed?

Comment: `resolvectl` is your friend.